# Converting active cell to hyperlink by searching through sheets name

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm not really into advanced VBA, just some basics, and I need a code that looks into activecell content and then search through worksheets names and then connect the activecell to the related sheet that has the same name as the activecell contents, by hyperlink. I would realllllllly appreciate, if you guys could help me.
**Thanks in advance!**
P.S: I searched through the posts but couldn't find any answer :/

The final and correct Code

```
Sub MakeHyperlink()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If ActiveCell.Value = Sheets(i).Name Then
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & _
        Sheets(i).Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell.Value
        End If
        Next i
ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim i, j, lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row

For j = 1 To lastrow

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

Cells(j, 4).Select

If Sheets(i).Name = Cells(j, 4).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        Sheets(i).Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Cells(j, 4).Value
End If

Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately again it generated a "reference not valid" error :/ I tried to make a hyperlink manually just to see if anything's wrong with my file and it did work, but by the Macro5 it didn't.

Comment: In which column/row is your activecell?

Comment: It's in column "C", the sheet is like a list with some names and a code number in column "C" which is the name of the related sheets.

Comment: I updated the macro so it refers to column "D" of you activesheet... hope it works now!

Comment: Actually when testing it on another file I just made, it worked, but when using it on my own file, it came with the same error, now I don't know what's the problem, but again thanks a lot for the favor, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I just found out that the problem is that my sheet names have dash signs in their names which VBA cannot use to make a reference, any suggestions?!!!

Comment: can you give an example of a value in the cell and the one in sheet name?

Comment: Thanks IRENE for the help, actually I found out the solution and that's that in SubAddress, after the equal sign and after the Sheets(i).name you need a single quotation mark i.e " ' " . This will validate the dash sign in the sheet name. It just made my day, thanks for the help.  > "-" <

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LinkUPsheets()
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        For Each lnk In Range("A1:A10")
            If lnk.Value = sht.Name Then
                lnk.Select
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                            Anchor:=Selection, _
                            Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:=sht.Name & "!A1", _
                            TextToDisplay:=lnk.Text
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it generates a "Reference isn't valid" error after running the code and clicking on the hyperlinked cell.